# Display arrays based on a certain number of characters

Tags: php, arrays

I've just seen a similar question and I'm trying to do something similar. I'm trying to display a number of arrays only if it has a certain name, well part of it.

the arrays are

```
upload_zzz_link_1
upload_zzz_link_2
upload_zzz_link_3
upload_zzz_link_4
upload_yyy_link_1
upload_www_link_1
upload_www_link_2
```

Here's a var_dump

```
["upload_zzz_link_1"]=> string(105) "http://www.blahblah.com/image_link.jpg" 
["upload_zzz_link_2"]=> string(79) "http://www.blahblah.com/image_link.jpg" 
["upload_zzz_link_3"]=> string(79) "http://www.blahblah.com/image_link.jpg" 
["upload_yyy_link_1"]=> string(79) "http://www.blahblah.com/image_link.jpg"
```

Basically I only want to display the zzz images, so can and how do I display images that have the characters upload_zzz_link_ ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array();
$array['test_zzz_test1'] = 'Display me !';
$array['test_yyy_test2'] = 'Dont display me !';
$array['test_zzz_test3'] = 'Display me !';

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, 'zzz')) {
        var_dump($value);
    }

}
```

Output :

```
string(9) "Display me !"
string(9) "Display me !"
```

(Note that using strpos, it will match anything with 'zzz' anywhere in the keys of your array. You could use '_zzz_' in your case)

Comment: Thank you but I am very new to arrays and for loops, how do I implement this, I'm not sure if i'm being dumb or i've just been looking at it too hard. Here's my functions but i'm getting an error function tl_hero_image_option_callback() {
 $hero_options = get_option( 'hero_options' ); 
for each ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos('zzz', $key)) {
        var_dump($value);
    }
}

Comment: Well, you have to replace `$array` in the foreach loop by your array containing the upload_xxx_link keys.

Comment: Hi, Sorry I did that but it was the space between the for and each that through up the error, although i'm still not getting anything showing, here's my function function tl_hero_image_option_callback() {
 $hero_options = get_option( 'hero_options' ); 
foreach ($hero_options as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos('zzz', $key)) {
        var_dump($value);
    }
}

}

Comment: My bad, sorry. Correct code is : `strpos($key, 'zzz')`, not `strpos('zzz', $key)`. I will update my answer with a complete example and outputs

Comment: You beauty. Thank you very much, been trying to figure this out since yesterday.

Comment: Hi, i'm on my last part of that code now so if you can help me out with the final part that would be great, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24629066/show-divs-based-on-the-amount-of-arrays thanks.